# Need to override a KeyError and continue with the rest of the conditions in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

There are three dataframes fd1 fd2 fd3 which read from the main dataframe df.

```
fd1 = df[df[A].str.match(.*color.*) & df.C.isnull()]
fd2 = df[df[B].str.match(.*type.*) & df.C.isnull()]
fd3 = df[df[D].str.match(.*[tT]ype:.*) & df.C.isnull()]

for i in range(len(fd1)):
    writer.writerow([fd[col].values[i] for col in fd1.columns])

for i in range(len(fd2)):
    writer.writerow([fd2[col].values[i] for col in fd2.columns])

for i in range(len(fd3)):
    writer.writerow([fd3[col].values[i] for col in fd3.columns])
```

However B column is not present in df (B column may or may not be present..in this case it is not) and this throws a keyerror. How to override this exception and continue with fd3 and subsequently output fd1 and fd3.

Comment: `for col in fd.columns` shouldnt that be `for col in fd1.columns` instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1. skip by putting the relevant code under `if B in df.columns: ...`
2. use some sort of default data with `fd2 = df.get(B, default_df)`. Its behavior is similar to `dict.get(key, default_value)`.

Comment: `fd2 = df.get(B, default_df)`...isn't fd2 an entire dataframe..how does this condition run..is it like `fd2.columns =df.columns.get(B, default_df.columns)`